Why can't %s recognize a direct string in string formatting?
I tried to print this code and am getting this error. Can someone please explain it?
print("%s.%s" % uuid.uuid4(),'txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

I was expecting a full string like this "some-uuid-code.txt".

In 2024, write f"{uuid.uuid4()}.txt"

txt is being treated as a second argument to print, not a second operand to the % operator.

I actually know the f string formatting but could not figure out why 'txt' is getting ignored while the exact string passed by a reference gets accepted.
ext='txt'
print("%s.%s" % uuid.uuid4(),ext) # works fine ...
but the code written above fails :') ... I just had to wrap in parenthesis

Wrap it in parentheses:
print("%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(),'txt'))

